# How to get specific value from JSON object?

Tags: java, android, json, getjson

I have A JSON where I am getting "Floor", "flat_no" and "Flat_id". So I am getting them like this.

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "Flat_id": "1",
        "cat": "2",
        "Flat_no": "101",
        "Floor": "1",
        "Flat_type": "1 bhk",
    },
    {
        "Flat_id": "2",
        "cat": "2",
        "Flat_no": "102",
        "Floor": "1",
        "Flat_type": "2 bhk",
    },
    {
        "Flat_id": "3",
        "cat": "2",
        "Flat_no": "103",
        "Floor": "1",
        "Flat_type": "3 bhk",
    },
    {
        "Flat_id": "4",
        "cat": "2",
        "Flat_no": "104",
        "Floor": "1",
        "Flat_type": "1 rk",
    },
    {
        "Flat_id": "5",
        "cat": "2",
        "Flat_no": "201",
        "Floor": "2",
        "Flat_type": "1 bhk",
        "Floor plan": "http://vaserp.com/floor_plan/img1_1157img1_354454.png"
    },
    {
        "Flat_id": "6",
        "cat": "2",
        "Flat_no": "202",
        "Floor": "2",
        "Flat_type": "2 bhk",
        "Floor plan": "http://vaserp.com/floor_plan/img1_218706img1_1188632.png"
    },
    {
        "Flat_id": "7",
        "cat": "2",
        "Flat_no": "203",
        "Floor": "2",
        "Flat_type": "3 bhk",
    },
    {
        "Flat_id": "8",
        "cat": "2",
        "Flat_no": "204",
        "Floor": "2",
        "Flat_type": "1 rk",
    }
]
```

}

I know JSON parsing. But I need A "Floor", and after that all flat and their id of that particular "Floor". I've attached an image, which show how I need to show the data ? Where "22" is floor and "201 to 205" are flat no.
So please help me how can I sort this problem ?

I tried like this

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
    allFloorDetailArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray(JSONUrl.TAG_RESULT);
    for (int i = 0; i < allFloorDetailArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = allFloorDetailArray.getJSONObject(i);
        FloorDetailItem floorDetailItem = new FloorDetailItem();
        floorDetailItem.setCat(c.getString(JSONUrl.TAG_CAT));
        floorDetailItem.setFlatNo(c.getString(JSONUrl.TAG_FLAT_NO));
        floorDetailItem.setFloor(c.getString(JSONUrl.TAG_FLOOR));
        floorNo = c.getString(JSONUrl.TAG_FLOOR);
        floorDetailItem.setFlatType(c.getString(JSONUrl.TAG_FLATE_TYPE));
        floorDetailItem.setFloorPlanImage(c.getString(JSONUrl.TAG_FLOOR_PLAN));

        mListDetailFloor.add(floorDetailItem);

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't get your problem. please explain more!

Comment: I mean i need floor no at the place of 22(see image), and as you can see I have "Floor" in every object. So it must come only 1 time and its all flat must com like 201 to 205(see image). SO I mean I need Floor 1 time and its all flat must come along with.

Comment: @AmitJayaswal you need to parse whole JSON and you need to manipulate data to show. it will not be a good way to leave some data while parsing.

Comment: I mean I am getting Floor "1" 4 times, but it must show only 1 time and the flat 101, 102, 103, 104, must show like the image

Comment: you can parse your whole json and group your objects by floor no.

Comment: I parsed the JSON as you can see the code but I am not able to group objects by floor no.

Comment: I think your JSON is not valid please remove the ```,``` for the last entry each item in results.

Comment: @Karthikeyan JSON is valid, I parsed it successfully. But I am not able to show it as I want

Comment: Buddy Use Hashmap<int,Arraylist<yourobjects>> data = create new instance;  then data.put(your floor number as key, list of flats);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use HashMap with floor as key and flat list as value :

**Note :** Your Json response is invalid in some flat json object like when "Floor plan" not came in flat json after "Flat_type" (,) comma is invalid

```
String jsonString = "{\"results\":[{\"Flat_id\":\"1\",\"cat\":\"2\",\"Flat_no\":\"101\",\"Floor\":\"1\",\"Flat_type\":\"1 bhk\"},{\"Flat_id\":\"2\",\"cat\":\"2\",\"Flat_no\":\"102\",\"Floor\":\"1\",\"Flat_type\":\"2 bhk\"},{\"Flat_id\":\"3\",\"cat\":\"2\",\"Flat_no\":\"103\",\"Floor\":\"1\",\"Flat_type\":\"3 bhk\"},{\"Flat_id\":\"4\",\"cat\":\"2\",\"Flat_no\":\"104\",\"Floor\":\"1\",\"Flat_type\":\"1 rk\"},{\"Flat_id\":\"5\",\"cat\":\"2\",\"Flat_no\":\"201\",\"Floor\":\"2\",\"Flat_type\":\"1 bhk\",\"Floor plan\":\"http://vaserp.com/floor_plan/img1_1157img1_354454.png\"},{\"Flat_id\":\"6\",\"cat\":\"2\",\"Flat_no\":\"202\",\"Floor\":\"2\",\"Flat_type\":\"2 bhk\",\"Floor plan\":\"http://vaserp.com/floor_plan/img1_218706img1_1188632.png\"},{\"Flat_id\":\"7\",\"cat\":\"2\",\"Flat_no\":\"203\",\"Floor\":\"2\",\"Flat_type\":\"3 bhk\"},{\"Flat_id\":\"8\",\"cat\":\"2\",\"Flat_no\":\"204\",\"Floor\":\"2\",\"Flat_type\":\"1 rk\"}]}";
HashMap<String,Object> floorMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
try{
     JSONObject responseJson =  new JSONObject(jsonString);
     JSONArray  resultJsonArray = responseJson.getJSONArray("results");

     for (int i=0;i<resultJsonArray.length();i++){
          if(floorMap.containsKey(resultJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Floor"))){
              ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> flatList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) floorMap.get(resultJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Floor"));
              HashMap<String,String> flatMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
              flatMap.put("Flat_id",resultJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Flat_id"));
              flatMap.put("Flat_no",resultJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Flat_no"));
              flatList.add(flatMap);
              floorMap.put(resultJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Floor"),flatList);
          }else{
              ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> flatList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
              HashMap<String,String> flatMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
              flatMap.put("Flat_id",resultJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Flat_id"));
              flatMap.put("Flat_no",resultJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Flat_no"));
              flatList.add(flatMap);
              floorMap.put(resultJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Floor"),flatList);
          }
    }

}catch (Throwable e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Iterator it = floorMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
   Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
   System.out.print("Floor :: "+pairs.getKey());
   ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> flatList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) pairs.getValue();
   for(HashMap<String,String> flat : flatList){
       System.out.print("Flat_id :: "+flat.get("Flat_id"));
       System.out.print("Flat_no :: "+flat.get("Flat_no"));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your 'Floor' is unique, you can use `HashMap`.

```
HashMap<int,Yourflatobjectlist> data = new HashMap<int,Yourflatobjectlist>();

data.put(floornumber as a key, List of Flat present at that Floor) ;
```